# Java bit comparison, bitset?

Tags: java, hex, logic, bit, bitset

I've got the word 'bitset' stuck in my head as the solution to my problem but I think I might be getting myself confused.

I've got a list of hex values that indicate certain conditions, such as:

```
0x0001 = Outside
0x20000000 = Blah...
```

Now I'm reading in an int, and I basically want to compare the int against all of the existing hex conditions to see which it matches.  It can match zero, one, or many.

Is a bitset actually what I want, or is there a simpler way of doing it?

I feel a bit silly for asking this, but I can't remember what the sodding thing is called! :)

Many thanks

Comment: Looks like you're looking for an `enum` and a `switch`?

Comment: Does a specific bit mean something? If not, I would go with plain `enum`.

Comment: Well the problem I've got is there about 40 or so conditions within the 32 bits of the int and I didn't really want to have 40 if statements for each.  I've seen something in the past using C code, but I cannot for the life of me remember what it was.

Comment: so 1 bit can actually represent more than one condition? ( 32 bits, 40 conditions?) or am I missing something here?

Comment: Sorry, I got my wires crossed, there are 15 conditions, I'll update

Comment: You can use a `long`, which gives you enough bits for 40 conditions. An `enum` and an `EnumSet` is probably more maintenance-friendly.

Comment: Might help ( not sure so not posting as answer) : loop through, shifting the bits right. At each iteration, check if the LSB is set or not, and so you can set condition[i] depending on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for bitmasking? This is where each bit in an `int` represents a boolean value, set (1, means true) and unset (0, means false). For example:

```
public class MaskingExample {

    private static final int OUTSIDE_MASK = 1; // Right-most bit
    private static final int HEATED_MASK = 1 << 1; // Second-to-right-most bit
    private static final int WET_MASK = 1 << 2; // Third-to-right-most bit

    private int value = 0;

    public boolean isOutside() {
        return isBitSet(OUTSIDE_MASK, value);
    }

    public void setOutside(boolean outside) {
        value = outside ? setBit(OUTSIDE_MASK, value) : unsetBit(OUTSIDE_MASK, value);
    }

    // Other setters and getters

    private static int setBit(int mask, int value) {
        return value | mask;
    }

    private static int unsetBit(int mask, int value) {
        return value & ~mask;
    }

    private static boolean isBitSet(int mask, int value) {
        return (value & mask) == mask;
    }
}
```

If you need more than 32 conditions, use `long` for all the masks and `value`, and add an `L` to each of the `1` values being shifted, and you can have up to 64 conditions, like this:

```
private static final long OUTSIDE_MASK = 1L; // Right-most bit
private static final long HEATED_MASK = 1L << 1; // Second-to-right-most bit
private static final long WET_MASK = 1L << 2; // Third-to-right-most bit

private long value = 0;
```

You can also set more than one bit at a time too, by the way. You combine masks together into a single mask using `&`:

```
public void setOutsideAndRaining(boolean outsideAndRaining) {
    int comboMask = OUTSIDE_MASK & WET_MASK;
    value = outsideAndRaining ? setBit(comboMask, value) : unsetBit(comboMask, value);
}
```

**Edit:** After seeing kaliatech's answer below, you could also use [`BitSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html). The solution is very similar, but the math logic is encapsulated in the `BitSet` object and it allows for an arbitrary number of bits so you aren't limited to only 64.

```
public class MaskingExample {

    private static final int OUTSIDE_POSITION = 0;
    private static final int HEATED_POSITION = 1;
    private static final int WET_POSITION = 2;
    private static final int TOTAL_CONDITIONS = 3;

    private BitSet bitSet = new BitSet(TOTAL_CONDITIONS);

    public boolean isOutside() {
        return bitSet.get(OUTSIDE_POSITION);
    }

    public void setOutside(boolean outside) {
        bitSet.set(OUTSIDE_POSITION, outside);
    }

    // Other setters and getters
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly clear what you want, but the Java SDK does provide a [BitSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html), along with a number of useful methods for working with BitSets.  In your case, the and() and intersects() methods might be of use.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know Java had this class. +1

Answer (score 1):

I think the word you're after is "bitmask"